# GLSL: sequential vec2 alignment in std140?

Tags: c++, glsl, std140

I am failing to understand vec2 alignment and offset rules in std140 layout:

I expected from the reading of the rule
"If the member is a two- or four-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 2N or 4N, respectively. "

that

```c
layout(std140, binding = 2) uniform material_t {
  vec2 scale;
  float textureSizeX;
  float textureSizeY;
} mat;
```

and

```c
layout(std140, binding = 2) uniform material_t {
  vec2 scale;
  vec2 textureSize;
} mat;
```

would be equivalent:

- N = sizeof(float)
- scale has offset 0, size 2 * N
- textureSize has offset 8, size 2 * N, alignement = 2 * N, and since 8 == 2 * sizeof(float) everything is neatly packed.

I'd expect my CPU-side struct

```
struct VideoMaterialUBO
{
  float scale[2];
  float textureSize[2];
};
static_assert(sizeof(VideoMaterialUBO) == 4 * sizeof(float));
```

to cleanly map to these two cases.

Alas, this isn't what I observe: I see that `VideoMaterialUBO` corresponds to the first UBO I posted - if I use the second UBO definition, `textureSize == vec2(0,0)`.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was actually not related to the layout, but to the `textureSize` name for my uniform member which was actually text-replaced in `_textureSize` by a lower layer of my shader stack due to name collision with the GLSL function